# Cual es la diferencia en declarar un id, en xml android, con un punto o guión bajo?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

por ejemplo cual es la diferencia en poner un id asi:

`android:id="@+id/comercio.tv.direccion"`

a poner un id asi:

```
android:id="@+id/comercio_tv_direccion"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Definir el id de un recurso conteniendo un punto es incorrecto,** por lo tanto esto no es posible:

```
android:id="@+id/comercio.tv.direccion"
```

por lo tanto lo correcto es definir de esta forma el id:

```
android:id="@+id/comercio_tv_direccion"
```

Los nombres de recursos o id deben seguir la siguiente convenciòn:

> "File names or ids must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore""

en español:

> "Los nombres o identificadores de recursos deben
>   contener solo minúsculas a-z, 0-9 o guión bajo "